# Trouble sending Bundle with PendingIntent to a Broadcast Receiver, data lost

Tags: android, bundle, broadcastreceiver

I am adding some basic alarm functionality to my program via the use of AlarmManager and a BroadcastReceiver class (named AReceiver.java).  My problem is that the data I add to the bundle attached to the Intent creating the PendingIntent appears to be lost.  The only bundle data I can access in the AReceiver class is a android.intent.extra.ALARM_COUNT=1.

Here is the basic code in the main activity class creating the Intent, PendingIntent and the AlarmManager:
[Code in main activity - Notepadv3]

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Notepadv3.this, AReceiver.class);         
intent.putExtra("teststring","hello, passed string in Extra");               
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, pendingPeriodIntentId, intent, 0);     
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);           
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOfNextPeriod.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

[Code in the BroadcastReceiver - AReceiver]

```
public void onReceive(Context con, Intent arg1) {
Bundle extrasBundle = arg1.getExtras();
Log.d("broadcast","contains teststring = " + extrasBundle.containsKey("teststring"));
Log.d("broadcast","is empty? = " + extrasBundle.isEmpty());
Log.d("broadcast","to string = " + extrasBundle.toString());
    }
```

Debug messages say that contains teststring is FALSE, is empty is FALSE and when outputting the whole bundle, I get the android.intent.extra.ALARM_COUNT=1 value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 35):

You have to change this line

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, pendingPeriodIntentId, intent, 0);
```

into this

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, pendingPeriodIntentId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

otherwise the data is lost

Comment: Thank you!  That was the fix, I had searched high and low to get the right parameters.  Thanks again.

Comment: strange, on android 4.0.3 emulator it works with both 0 and PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: BUT... when you do the latter, it OVERWRITES any *existing* extras.  Meaning if we want to add new extras AND retain the existing one, it doesn't work.  Normally passing 0 as flags causes this works (e.g. if calling send on the PendingIntent instead of scheduling it with AlarmManager). What gives?

Comment: For Android 4.4.2 even with flags set to 0 I can retrieve extras from Intent while in Android 5 extras are lost even using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT,