# Intent is not sending data on "SMS_SENT" receiver on android v4.0.3

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I've run this code over different devices... and I'am not receiving any data from intent in receiver on HTC desire C, android OS 4.0.3.
I don't know why?????

My sample code is here...

**Sendind Data(tag) Over Intent**

```
public void sendSMS(String tag)
{   
    Log.v("number", number);
    String numbers[] = number.split(",");
    Delivered deliveryReciever [] = new Delivered[numbers.length];
    Sent sentReciever[] = new Sent[numbers.length];
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
    {
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPI = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        Intent sentIntent = new Intent(context,Sent.class);
        Log.v("ctag","sms:"+tag);
        sentIntent.putExtra("mtag", tag);
        sentIntent.setAction(SENT);
        sentPI.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,sentIntent, 0));

        ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveredPI = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        sentPI.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,new Intent(DELIVERED), 0));

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message); 

        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(numbers[i], null, parts, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }
}
```

**here broadcast receiver**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    switch (getResultCode())
    {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
        Log.v("ctag here","sent:"+intent.getStringExtra("mtag"));
        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent"+intent.getStringExtra("mtag"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
        Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
        Toast.makeText(context, "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are registering the receiver... but just after you are unregistering it. So your receiver cannot be triggered because you are unregistering it.

Comment: ooopss.. this was my flaw too.. but this doesn't solve my issue. Issue is, why i am receiving null from intent in receiver??

Comment: actually these lines don't do any thing in my code
deliveryReciever[i] = new Delivered();
        sentReciever[i] = new Sent();

        context.registerReceiver(sentReciever[i], new IntentFilter(SENT));
        context.registerReceiver(deliveryReciever[i], new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

all work is done my pending intent...

Answer (score 0):

you are never registering your receiver now...
Yes you are giving the list of pending intents to SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage, which will trigger your pending intent once the sms is received by broadcasting the intent with the action you specified (which is DELIVERED).

But you are not registering the receiver... so the broadcast is sent by the SmsManager, and never received by you.

You should register the receiver by doing :
final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DELIVERED);
context.registerReceiver(YOUR_BROADCAST_RECEIVER, filter);

Comment: refering to [this][1]...
actually issue was in 

    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,sentIntent, 0);

I just replaced it with

    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,sentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

now its working fine. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3736327/3748706

Answer (score 0):

refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3736327/3748706)...
actually issue was in

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,sentIntent, 0);
```

I just replaced it with

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,sentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

now its working fine.