# Android AppWidget RemoteViewsFactory intent and putSerializable/putParcelable

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appwidget, remoteview

In my widget i have the setup required for intents in collections 
(setPendingIntentTemplate) in my `AppWidgetProvider` subclass on method `onUpdate`

and on my `RemoteViewsFactory` `getViewAt` method i have:

```
 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
 extras.putInt("pos", position);
 extras.putInt("date", new DateTime().millisOfDay().get());

 //comment this to work
 extras.putSerializable("d", new DateTime());

 Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
 fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);

 // Make it possible to distinguish the individual on-click
 // action of a given item
 row.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.list_view_row, fillInIntent);
```

Im facing the issue that my activity gets started but has no extras from the `getViewAt`method, however as soon as i comment the `extras.putSerializable("d", new DateTime());` statement 
the activity gets all other extras as excepted the same happens for `Parcelable` extras,
is it documented anywhere that `AppWidgets` `setOnClickFillInIntent` don´t support `Parcelable`and `Serializable` extras ?

Edit:
Im using the following intent template:

```
 Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    //startActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    startActivityIntent
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
            .setData(Uri.parse(startActivityIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));


    PendingIntent startActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getActivity(context, 0, startActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.list, startActivityPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what kind of flag are you passing in the PendingIntent in your AppWidgetProvider
[Trouble sending Bundle with PendingIntent to a Broadcast Receiver, data lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729007/trouble-sending-bundle-with-pendingintent-to-a-broadcast-receiver-data-lost)